# Convert hex string to bytearray and write to file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, io

I wrote one app using C# to read data from a serial port and show the data on a textbox in hex string format. Finally, I saved all data to a binary file. If data is big (maybe > 20mb) it throws an out of memory error. How can I solve this? Here is my code:

```
private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog save_log = new SaveFileDialog();
    save_log.DefaultExt = ".bin";
    save_log.Filter = "Binary File (*.bin)|*.bin";
    // Determine if the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog.
    if (save_log.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
        save_log.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            string hexString = Content.Text.ToString();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(save_log.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            stream.Write(Hex_to_ByteArray(hexString), 0, Hex_to_ByteArray(hexString).Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private byte[] Hex_to_ByteArray(string s)
{
    s = s.Replace(" ", "");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
    {
        buffer[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: If you have the data as it has been read from the serial port (in `byte[]` format maybe), why don't you keep that around and write it to the file if needed? That way, you don't have to convert the Hex-string back to binary.

Comment: that's good idea but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Don't do everything by yourself. Use `encoding`. This source might help you http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695963/How-to-Read-and-Write-String-Array-in-Binary-File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating the byte array twice. Also, the `.Replace` over such a long string doesn't help. You can avoid all this:

```
try
{
    var stream = new FileStream(
        save_log.FileName,
        FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    WriteHexStringToFile(Content.Text, stream);

    stream.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}

private void WriteHexStringToFile(string hexString, FileStream stream)
{
    var twoCharacterBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    var oneByte = new byte[1];
    foreach (var character in hexString.Where(c => c != ' '))
    {
        twoCharacterBuffer.Append(character);

        if (twoCharacterBuffer.Length == 2)
        {
            oneByte[0] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(twoCharacterBuffer.ToString(), 16);
            stream.Write(oneByte, 0, 1);
            twoCharacterBuffer.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, take a look at [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) and/or [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which might do all of this for you.

**Update:**

First of all, please note that your whole idea of storing megabytes of data in a string is a nonsense, and you shouldn't do that. You should process your data in smaller parts. Because of this nonsense I'm unable to provide you with a working demo (on IDEONE for example), because of resource limitations of online compilers. I've tested the code on my machine, and as you can see I can even process 50 MB strings - but it all depends on the amount of memory you have available. If you do such things, then on every machine it will be easy to reach the limit of available memory. And the methods you ask about in this particular question are irrelevant - the problem is because you fill your memory with tons of data in your `Content.Text` string. When memory is almost full, the `OutOfMemoryException` can occur at almost any place in your code.

You can view the whole picture in your browser to see all the details.

[image: note the freehand circles]

Comment: tks, it look great, have to make some tests before accepting it as aswer

Comment: @Green `OutOfMemoryException` is not likely to be produced by this code alone. On which line exactly do you see it?

Comment: @Green Please try the updated version. I've removed all unnecessary memory allocations.

Comment: it still crash, it's only ok with small file. I can't debug with this code, data is too much for debug line by line. It has error from <code>foreach (var character in hexString.Where(c => c != ' '))</code> and I dont know extactly which line cause error. Can you test your code by create a file with wall of hex string like "71 71 71 ...." in text editor, paste to C# and test it?

Comment: @Green I'll gladly test the code, but please provide more details. The number of line should be displayed in exception message/exception details. What file size triggers the exception? What do you mean "line by line"? You've indicated just one line - so it's `OutOfMemory` exception on the `foreach` line?

Comment: I create wall of text "71 71 71 71 ...." in another text editor and paste to richtexbox, it can save the file up to 30mb. If the file is bigger, it throw error: "unhandled exception: system.outofmemoryexception" and arrow to foreach (var character in hexString.Where(c => c != ' ')). I dont know why  catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
not work.

Comment: I can do the test like your picture (save string from stringbuilder to file directly)  without error. When I write that stringbuilder to richtexbox, clear that stringbuilder then save richtexbox.Text again to file, it cause same error I said. Can you explain this for me ? I really don't understand. Does both of it use same memory ?

Comment: @Green Yes, every piece of information you have in your program uses memory. `RichTextBox` (and any other control, excluding some very elaborate that would be designed especially for large data - but I don't know of any) also needs to store the data it displays in memory, and many other information regarding its looks, formatting etc. WinForms controls aren't designed to handle such numbers of bytes.

Comment: why getting data from richtextbox to write file cause error while getting data from stringbuilder don't cause error ?

Comment: @Green There are many possibilities, but two important things to note are: 1) you're working in a GC environment (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example). The fact that you clear the `StringBuilder` doesn't mean that the memory gets released at once. So in your scenario with the `RichTextBox` it's possible that twice as much memory is allocated. 2) Controls are usually "heavy", and `RichTextBox` is "heavy" for sure (in the meaning it uses lots of resources). So it uses much more memory that a `string` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Use IEnumerable.  That will avoid the large byte array.

I don't know what is in Content.Text.  If it's a byte array, maybe you can change

```
static internal IEnumerable<byte>Hex_to_Byte(string s)
```

into

```
static internal IEnumerable<byte>Hex_to_Byte(byte[] bytes)
```

and modify the code a bit

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(save_log.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
foreach( byte b in Hex_to_Byte(hexString) )
    stream.WriteByte(b);
stream.Close();



    static internal IEnumerable<byte>Hex_to_Byte(string s)
    {
        bool haveFirstByte = false;
        int firstByteValue = 0;

        foreach( char c in s)
        {
            if( char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
                continue;

            if( !haveFirstByte)
            {
                haveFirstByte = true;
                firstByteValue = GetHexValue(c) << 4;
            }
            else
            {
                haveFirstByte = false;
                yield return unchecked((byte)(firstByteValue + GetHexValue(c)));
            }

        }

    }
    static string hexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    static int GetHexValue(char c)
    {
        int v = hexChars.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(c));
        if (v < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("c", string.Format("not a hex char: {0}"));
        return v;
    }
```